Map function without passing it a function
I'm trying to improve my skills in data science with some courses, and today I was taking a lesson about missing values and how to deal with them. During the lesson it showed this code:
# Calculate median plane ticket prices by Airline
airline_prices = planes.groupby("Airline")["Price"].median()

print(airline_prices)

# Convert to a dictionary
prices_dict = airline_prices.to_dict()

# Map the dictionary to missing values of Price by Airline
planes["Price"] = planes["Price"].fillna(planes["Airline"].map(prices_dict))

# Check for missing values
print(planes.isna().sum())

I'm having difficult to understand what the map function does in this case. I know that map function applies a function to every item of the iterable passed as second argument, but in this case is passed only the iterable argument (which is a dictionary in this case). Please tell me if I'm right or not: in that line of code for every row of the 'Price' column that has a na value the fillna function fill it with the median of each group of 'Airline'. In this the map function simply associate every 'Airline' to the corresponding median? Why the map function works without a func passed to it?

The function you're calling here is Series.map. Unlike DataFrame.map, this function also accepts a dict as input:
Parameters:
arg: function, collections.abc.Mapping subclass or Series Mapping correspondence.


in that line of code for every row of the 'Price' column that has a na value the fillna function fill it with the median of each group of 'Airline'.

Yes. If the key doesn't exist in the map, nan (or the default dict value) will be assigned, but in this case, since you're doing a group by on "airline" on the same dataframe, that will never be the case.

Oh okay i think I have understood now. So, firstly, the map function substitute the name of the airline (key of the dictionary passed as a argument) with the median price (value of the dictionary) and then the fillna function substitute all the na values in price column with the median of the corresponding airline, is it right?

@LucÀ yes, if the plane doesn't have a price, it will be assigned the median price for that plane's airline.
